# Javascript how to change font properties to script?

Tags: javascript, fonts, output

I found this script which is perfect for what I need. However I would like to change the font properties to make it bold and red for the result displayed. I looked all over and tried adding it but somehow I just seem to make it not function at all when I do. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentValue = 35;
    var add = function(valueToAdd){
        currentValue += valueToAdd;
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = currentValue;

    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setAttribute to this element in DOM tree:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentValue = 35;
    var add = function(valueToAdd){
        currentValue += valueToAdd;
    var el = document.getElementById('number');
        el.innerHTML = currentValue;
        el.setAttribute('style', 'font-weight:bold; color:red;')
    };
</script>
```

Comment: This is perfect. I am very grateful thank you so much!

Comment: Not to be a pain, but I just realized this isn't saved on the webpage. I need to be able  to have this saved so when 1 is added or removed, then the new number is visible when someone else goes to the page. Here is the link of what I have so far: http://peredyizhere.com/ppreq/donocount.html

Comment: If you you mean case when user 1 set value from 35 to 30 and close page. And user 2 after that open page page and see 30.. You need send your changes to server and get back from it on page load..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting the element and storing it in a variable for easier use.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentValue = 35;
    var add = function(valueToAdd){
        var elem = document.getElementById('number');
        currentValue += valueToAdd;
        elem.style.color = 'red';
        elem.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        elem.innerHTML = currentValue;
    };
</script>
```

Not recommended but this is without an element variable above is cleaner and better code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentValue = 35;
    var add = function(valueToAdd){
        currentValue += valueToAdd;
        document.getElementById('number').style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('number').style.fontWeight = "bold";
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = currentValue;
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `style` attribute to update the styles:

```
document.getElementById('number').style.color = 'red';
document.getElementById('number').style.fontWeight = 'bold';
```